# Using variable value as net name

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have following lines of Verilog code:

```
mySwitch  simblock_out_a_inst0 (.aa(simblock_if_h[0].simblock_out_a),.bb(BLOCK_out_a_inst0),.CloseIfHi(simblock_if_h[0].enable));
mySwitch  simblock_out_b_inst0 (.aa(simblock_if_h[0].simblock_out_b),.bb(BLOCK_out_b_inst0),.CloseIfHi(simblock_if_h[0].enable));
mySwitch  simblock_out_c_inst0 (.aa(simblock_if_h[0].simblock_out_c),.bb(BLOCK_out_c_inst0),.CloseIfHi(simblock_if_h[0].enable));
mySwitch  simblock_out_d_inst0 (.aa(simblock_if_h[0].simblock_out_d),.bb(BLOCK_out_d_inst0),.CloseIfHi(simblock_if_h[0].enable));

mySwitch  simblock_out_a_inst1 (.aa(simblock_if_h[1].simblock_out_a),.bb(BLOCK_out_a_inst1),.CloseIfHi(simblock_if_h[1].enable));
mySwitch  simblock_out_b_inst1 (.aa(simblock_if_h[1].simblock_out_b),.bb(BLOCK_out_b_inst1),.CloseIfHi(simblock_if_h[1].enable));
mySwitch  simblock_out_c_inst1 (.aa(simblock_if_h[1].simblock_out_c),.bb(BLOCK_out_c_inst1),.CloseIfHi(simblock_if_h[1].enable));
mySwitch  simblock_out_d_inst1 (.aa(simblock_if_h[1].simblock_out_d),.bb(BLOCK_out_d_inst1),.CloseIfHi(simblock_if_h[1].enable));
```

The above does work. But the above is for just 2 instances and the code can increase with multiple instances, which I am looking to avoid. Also, I would like to have the number of instances parameterized.

I was thinking of using `generate` statement, but due to net names like `BLOCK_out_d_inst1` (i.e. in non-array format), I'm unaware of how to implement that.

Any suggestions? Can I create a variable say, `var_net`, and use its value as a net?  E.g.:

```
var_net = BLOCK_out_d_inst1;
mySwitch  simblock_out_d_inst1 (.aa(simblock_if_h[1].simblock_out_d),.bb(var_net),.CloseIfHi(simblock_if_h[1].enable));
```

Comment: how is `simblock_if_h` declared?

Comment: simblock_if_h is an interface object. To remove complications, we might want to ignore the interface. We could perhaps simply look at it like "mySwitch  simblock_out_a_inst0 (.aa(out_a[0]),.bb(BLOCK_out_a_inst0),.CloseIfHi(enable));"

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `BLOCK_out_a_inst0`, etc., signals are 1-bit wide, you can create new bus wires, concatenating the signals together, then use a `generate`:

```
wire [1:0] BLOCK_out_a_inst = {BLOCK_out_a_inst1, BLOCK_out_a_inst0};
wire [1:0] BLOCK_out_b_inst = {BLOCK_out_b_inst1, BLOCK_out_b_inst0};
wire [1:0] BLOCK_out_c_inst = {BLOCK_out_c_inst1, BLOCK_out_c_inst0};
wire [1:0] BLOCK_out_d_inst = {BLOCK_out_d_inst1, BLOCK_out_d_inst0};

genvar i
for (i=0; i<2; i=i+1) begin : switch_num
    mySwitch simblock_out_a_inst (.aa(simblock_if_h[i].simblock_out_a), .bb(BLOCK_out_a_inst[i]), .CloseIfHi(simblock_if_h[i].enable));
    mySwitch simblock_out_b_inst (.aa(simblock_if_h[i].simblock_out_b), .bb(BLOCK_out_b_inst[i]), .CloseIfHi(simblock_if_h[i].enable));
    mySwitch simblock_out_c_inst (.aa(simblock_if_h[i].simblock_out_c), .bb(BLOCK_out_c_inst[i]), .CloseIfHi(simblock_if_h[i].enable));
    mySwitch simblock_out_d_inst (.aa(simblock_if_h[i].simblock_out_d), .bb(BLOCK_out_d_inst[i]), .CloseIfHi(simblock_if_h[i].enable));
end
```